# JQuery слайдшоу

Tags: jquery

Хочу сделать слайдшоу. Есть верстка.

html:

```
   <div id="container">
         <div id="slides">
              <img class="slideimg" src="img/cat1.jpg">
              <img class="slideimg" src="img/cat2.jpg">
              <img class="slideimg" src="img/cat3.jpg">
         </div>
    </div>
```

сss:

```
#container{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    position: relative;
    width: 660px;
    height: 387px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
.slideimg{
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#slides").animate({marginLeft:0},1000);
setTimeout(function({$("#slides").animate({marginLeft:-680},1500)},5000);                                 setTimeout(function({$("#slides").animate({marginLeft:-1380},1500)},10000);

});
```

Идея такая: в slides отображаются картинки. меняются за счёт смещения. Можно ли как нибудь зациклить? Сейчас работает. Нужно чтоб на 3ем слайде не останавливалось, а начиналось с первого слайда.
Если сильно говнокод, подскажите как сделать лучше?

Answer (score 1):

Если не стоит учебная задача - заюзайте [jQuery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). Мне понравился, а код всегда подшаманить можно

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgs = $('img.slideimg')
var next =  $(this).next().length ? $(this).next() : imgs.eq('0');
// проверяем есть ли элементы дальше, если массив пуст, а jquery возвращает пустой массив, если ничего не найдет, то берем первую картинку
//$(this) - текущий элемент слайдшоу
```

Comment: что то не получилось прикрутить. куда эту часть кода добавить?